# Code to mimic the RSS widget

Tags: rss

Background - I was using a (paid) theme, and spent quite a bit of time with customizing it. The result was an aggregator page, 4 columns of RSS feeds for the topic. The theme issued an update which, in effect, destroyed the work, and no longer supported what I wanted to do. Time to move on.

I searched for another paid theme that seemed to be popular, and flexible. No sooner do I load it and look at setting up a page, I see that the standard Wordpress widgets aren't there, just modules supported by the theme's authors.

Not one to quickly give up, I see that one module offers 'code', i.e. enter custom code in the text field.

TL;DR - Is there simple code available that mimics the wordpress RSS widget? (Or makes a call to that code without having the WP RSS widget in place?)

Comment: Have you considered figuring out how to undo the code that removes the official RSS widget? If you've opted to use a new theme that disables the core widgets then you should contact the theme vendor. Rebuilding the widget from scratch doesn't make sense. For future reference, make sure your changes are in a child theme so that when the theme updates your changes aren't lost

Comment: When creating a page, the standard WP widgets simply aren't there, the only options are the modules the theme provides. I was hoping that since the underlying WP code is still there, there was an easy way to call it from a code box. The vendor was kind, but gave a non answer, as in "that's not a module we offer".  No way to see this in advance of purchase, and kind of startled to see the widget set just not there.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by modules? Modules isn't standard WP terminology. Widgets in standard WP are supposed to appear on the main widget interface, not in post/page content editing, e.g. `/wp-admin/widgets.php`. It may be that the theme you've chosen and the theme you moved from don't use the standard post editor and have bundled in a custom page builder plugin. Can you share the name of the old/new themes? It may even be possible that you've never used the official RSS widget, or widgets at all

Comment: Yes. I had been using Thesis, and the RSS feed there is the standard WP widget, certain of that.  Divi by Elegant Themes runs a custom page builder as you suggest.  I am aware that I am used to working with themes that have widgetized areas, and are drag and drop.  For ex. "Elementor" has a free level. Page>Visual Builder> create X columns for widgets, and select from pallet. The choices are both custom from the theme, but include the  standard set I'm used to seeing.